# Blazor WASM view not using a variable from OnInitialized()

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm attempting to understand how Blazor WASM works. I've got a razor view that makes an API call and displays data based on the response.

Currently, the page loads and doesn't display anything. If I modify the page and hot-reload it within Visual Studio, the page displays data, and so I believe when the page loads, the message value is `null` hence the page doesn't display anything on load.

How can I get `message?.Name` to display on page load or very soon after?

Code:

```
<p class="">@message?.Name</p>

@code {
    public MessageDocumentationDto? message;

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        try
        {
            message = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<MessageDocumentationDto>("api/Documentation/ViewRecord");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() if you use the async version

Comment: @Santiago Thanks. Can you add it as an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() if you use the async version